# What is a proper way to omit a type when working with generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I have `HelperFunctions` class which contains a lot methods for my assignment.
One of those functions is simply printing the contents of an array:

```
    internal static void printArray(T[] arr)
    {
        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

The issue here is that `printArray` is the only function inside the class `HelperFunctions` which requires type arguments. And as such, any other function call, needs a random type.

example:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Result of challenge 1: " + HelperFunctions<int>.printB64Res(ch1.hexToB64()));
byte[] input1 = HelperFunctions<int>.ProperHex(this.text1);
byte[] input2 = HelperFunctions<int>.ProperHex(this.text2);
HelperFunctions<string>.printArray(HelperFunctions<int>.readFile(dir + @"\hashes.txt")); 
// printArray() is the only function which needs a type argument
```

What would be a better alternative here?

Comment: So only make `printArray` into a generic method? I'm not sure I understand the problem?

Comment: @UnholySheep I need to give a type to the class whenever I call anything from that specific class

Comment: But your question states that only that one method requires a type argument, so why do you need to have the entire class be generic?

Comment: I had no idea that that was possible. Apparently it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)

```cs
internal static void printArray<T>(T[] arr)
    {
        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had no idea that this was possible! Thanks!